# last Relative layout not displaying properly in android xml

Tags: xml, android-layout, layout

Hi in the below xml each every layout was working except last relative layout.for the each and every relative layout set the margin top after the next layout based on the above margin top.

But last relative layout was overriding with last 2nd layout .

**xml**

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:background="@drawable/frame1">

<RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_marginTop="900dp"
     android:background="@android:color/white" >

     <!-- This is the main content -->

     <RelativeLayout
         android:id="@+id/relativeLayout9"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="180dp"
         android:layout_margin="5dp"
         android:background="@drawable/frame1"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:padding="20dp" >

         <LinearLayout
             android:id="@+id/linearLayout9"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
             android:background="#DFECEB"
             android:orientation="vertical" >

             <LinearLayout
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                 <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/textView40"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                     android:padding="5dp"
                     android:text="Excellent"
                     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                     android:textSize="15sp"
                     android:textStyle="bold" />

                 <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/textView41"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                     android:padding="5dp"
                     android:text="Good"
                     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                     android:textSize="15sp"
                     android:textStyle="bold" />

                 <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/textView42"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                     android:padding="5dp"
                     android:text="Satisfactory"
                     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                     android:textSize="15sp"
                     android:textStyle="bold" />

                 <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/textView43"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                     android:padding="5dp"
                     android:text="Poor"
                     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                     android:textSize="15sp"
                     android:textStyle="bold" />
             </LinearLayout>

             <LinearLayout
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:orientation="horizontal" >

                 <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/textView44"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                     android:padding="5dp"
                     android:text="Helpfulness of Security staff"
                     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                     android:textSize="15sp"
                     android:textStyle="bold" />
             </LinearLayout>

             <LinearLayout
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:orientation="horizontal" >

                 <RadioGroup
                     android:id="@+id/security_helpfull"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                 </RadioGroup>

                 <RadioButton
                     android:id="@+id/radioButton53"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

                 <RadioButton
                     android:id="@+id/radioButton54"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="40dp" />

                 <RadioButton
                     android:id="@+id/radioButton55"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="40dp" />

                 <RadioButton
                     android:id="@+id/radioButton56"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" />
             </LinearLayout>



         </LinearLayout>


     </RelativeLayout>

     <TextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/relativeLayout9"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
         android:background="@android:color/white"
         android:padding="5dp"
         android:text="Security Services"
         android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

 </RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_marginTop="1090dp"
     android:background="@android:color/white" >

     <!-- This is the main content -->

     <RelativeLayout
         android:id="@+id/relativeLayout10"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="380dp"
         android:layout_margin="5dp"
         android:background="@drawable/frame1"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:padding="20dp" >

         <LinearLayout
             android:id="@+id/linearLayout10"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
             android:background="#DFECEB"
             android:orientation="vertical" >

             <LinearLayout
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                 <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/textView45"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                     android:padding="5dp"
                     android:text="Excellent"
                     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                     android:textSize="15sp"
                     android:textStyle="bold" />

                 <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/textView46"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                     android:padding="5dp"
                     android:text="Good"
                     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                     android:textSize="15sp"
                     android:textStyle="bold" />

                 <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/textView47"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                     android:padding="5dp"
                     android:text="Satisfactory"
                     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                     android:textSize="15sp"
                     android:textStyle="bold" />

                 <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/textView48"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                     android:padding="5dp"
                     android:text="Poor"
                     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                     android:textSize="15sp"
                     android:textStyle="bold" />
             </LinearLayout>

             <LinearLayout
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:orientation="horizontal" >

                 <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/textView57"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                     android:padding="5dp"
                     android:text="Friendliness"
                     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                     android:textSize="15sp"
                     android:textStyle="bold" />
             </LinearLayout>

             <LinearLayout
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:orientation="horizontal" >

                 <RadioGroup
                     android:id="@+id/staff_friendliness"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                 </RadioGroup>

                 <RadioButton
                     android:id="@+id/radioButton57"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

                 <RadioButton
                     android:id="@+id/radioButton58"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="40dp" />

                 <RadioButton
                     android:id="@+id/radioButton59"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="40dp" />

                 <RadioButton
                     android:id="@+id/radioButton60"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" />
             </LinearLayout>





         <LinearLayout
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:orientation="horizontal" >

                 <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/textView58"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                     android:padding="5dp"
                     android:text="Handling of problems"
                     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                     android:textSize="15sp"
                     android:textStyle="bold" />
             </LinearLayout>

             <LinearLayout
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:orientation="horizontal" >

                 <RadioGroup
                     android:id="@+id/staff_handling_problems"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                 </RadioGroup>

                 <RadioButton
                     android:id="@+id/radioButton61"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

                 <RadioButton
                     android:id="@+id/radioButton62"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="40dp" />

                 <RadioButton
                     android:id="@+id/radioButton63"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="40dp" />

                 <RadioButton
                     android:id="@+id/radioButton64"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" />
             </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:orientation="horizontal" >

                 <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/textView59"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                     android:padding="5dp"
                     android:text="Promptness"
                     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                     android:textSize="15sp"
                     android:textStyle="bold" />
             </LinearLayout>

             <LinearLayout
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:orientation="horizontal" >

                 <RadioGroup
                     android:id="@+id/staff_promptness"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                 </RadioGroup>

                 <RadioButton
                     android:id="@+id/radioButton65"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

                 <RadioButton
                     android:id="@+id/radioButton66"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="40dp" />

                 <RadioButton
                     android:id="@+id/radioButton67"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="40dp" />

                 <RadioButton
                     android:id="@+id/radioButton68"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" />
             </LinearLayout>


           </LinearLayout>  


     </RelativeLayout>


     <TextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/relativeLayout10"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
         android:background="@android:color/white"
         android:padding="5dp"
         android:text="Staff Attitude"
         android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

 </RelativeLayout>
 <RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_marginTop="1098dp"
     android:background="@android:color/white" >

     <!-- This is the main content -->
<RelativeLayout
         android:id="@+id/relativeLayout11"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="180dp"
         android:layout_margin="5dp"
         android:background="@drawable/frame1"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:padding="20dp" >

         <LinearLayout
             android:id="@+id/linearLayout11"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
             android:background="#DFECEB"
             android:orientation="vertical" >

             <LinearLayout
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                 <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/textView60"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                     android:padding="5dp"
                     android:text="*"
                     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                     android:textSize="15sp"
                     android:textStyle="bold" />

                 <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/textView61"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                     android:padding="5dp"
                     android:text="**"
                     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                     android:textSize="15sp"
                     android:textStyle="bold" />

                 <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/textView62"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                     android:padding="5dp"
                     android:text="***"
                     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                     android:textSize="15sp"
                     android:textStyle="bold" />

                 <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/textView63"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                     android:padding="5dp"
                     android:text="****"
                     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                     android:textSize="15sp"
                     android:textStyle="bold" />
                 <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/textView64"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                     android:padding="5dp"
                     android:text="****"
                     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                     android:textSize="15sp"
                     android:textStyle="bold" />
             </LinearLayout>

             <LinearLayout
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:orientation="horizontal" >

                 <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/textView65"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                     android:padding="5dp"
                     android:text="Over all how would you rate the hospital?"
                     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                     android:textSize="15sp"
                     android:textStyle="bold" />
             </LinearLayout>

             <LinearLayout
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:orientation="horizontal" >

                 <RadioGroup
                     android:id="@+id/rating"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                 </RadioGroup>

                 <RadioButton
                     android:id="@+id/radioButton69"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

                 <RadioButton
                     android:id="@+id/radioButton70"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="40dp" />

                 <RadioButton
                     android:id="@+id/radioButton71"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="40dp" />

                 <RadioButton
                     android:id="@+id/radioButton72"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" />
                 <RadioButton
                     android:id="@+id/radioButton73"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" />
             </LinearLayout>



         </LinearLayout>

  </RelativeLayout>      

      <TextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/relativeLayout11"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
         android:background="@android:color/white"
         android:padding="5dp"
         android:text="Rating"
         android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

 </RelativeLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `LinearLayout` instead of `FrameLayout`. It's a bad practice to set margin to position components on after another.
Or use `android:layout_below` or `android:layout_above` for inner `RelativeLayout`.